# MySQL: How creating a function that queries with variables columns names

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, sql-function

I am trying to make a function witch create a new ID from any table given as parameter.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS create_id;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION create_id(db_table TEXT,pkey TEXT,strlen INT,joinner TEXT)
  RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
    DECLARE max_id TEXT;
    DECLARE new_id TEXT;
    SET max_id = (SELECT MAX(pkey) FROM db_table);
    SET new_id = max_id;
    RETURN new_id;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: That is a **really**, really bad idea. It's simply not going to work correctly if you have multiple transactions doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use variables like you want to; basically, if you want a variable identifier (table name, column name or the-like), you need to use dynamic SQL. But MySQL functions do not support dynamic SQL. So, instead, you need to use a procedure with an `OUT` paramter.

Consider:

```
drop procedure if exists create_id;
delimiter $$

create procedure create_id(in _db_table text, in _pkey text, out _max_id int)
begin
    set @max_id = null;
    set @sql = concat('select max(`', _pkey, '`)  into @max_id from `', _db_table, '`');
    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
    set _max_id = @max_id;
end;
$$

delimiter ;
```

Then, you invoke the procedure and recover the out value like so:

```
call create_id('mytable', 'id', @max_id);
select @max_id;
```

Note: I couldn't see the point for the last two arguments to your original function, so I removed them.

Comment: Can I call this new procedure in another procedure definition?

Comment: THANK YOU FOR ASSISTANCE. Please, Can I call this new procedure in another procedure definition?